# VS2013 Server Explorer failing with Storage Account required

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I use Visual Studio 2013 server explorer to access my Windows azure services.  Accessing storage (tables) stopped working yesterday (1/29/2014).  Since then I have re-generated the keys multiple times and re-registered settings from my services.

Notice all other connectivity to Azure works fine (ie: web sites, etc). It is only an issue with Storage.

Is anyone else encountering this issue ? Any solution ??

thanks

[Server Explorer Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/citBp.png)

Comment: Can you regenerate keys?

Comment: Yes, I have regenerated them, and copy them, multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog window where you can select which connection you want to use select `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS (recommended)`.